# Using curl I am not getting whole html while scraping, why?

Tags: php, curl

For example, I tried to scrape meta tags for yebhi.com and for some pages its coming back as null.

I'm using the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.yebhi.com/253196/PD/Tech-Graphic-Tee-81703611.htm');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am not getting the html properly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'html properly' what does this mean, what HTML are you getting back?

Comment: i am getting the html but some of the HTML goes away. Its anonymous. When i view source the page i got the html properly. But via CURL or DOM i am not getting the full html

Comment: Please try the above code. You will get to know what i am trying to convey.